# Should I have a central place to manage all threads in a multithreaded application?

Tags: c++, multithreading

First of all, I'm not sure if a thread pool would fit my case:

- Main thread is UI, which receives user command and delegate to other modules for actions.
- Other modules run in their own threads spawned from main thread, each performing different tasks that aren't similar.
- These other threads may conditionally spawn child threads.

All these threads are going to be `std::thread`. Those tasks are different enough that I don't know if a thread pool would be helpful. Only a few threads need to report back to main thread. Most can quit at any time.

Should I hold a collection of thread handles somewhere for managing them? Some thoughts of having a central place:

Pros

- I can keep track of all the threads, tweak their priority, and kill them easily.

Cons

- Instead of spawning threads from other threads, I now have to create a messaging framework to delegate everything to the thread manager module to do it. Not sure if this complexity is bigger than not having a thread manager.

Thoughts and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a messaging framework to have a central place to manage threads. You can have a central place in the sense of a collection and a bunch of code that can be accessed and executed by any thread whenever it needs to create or manage a thread. You don't need a message framework because you don't care what thread does some work -- they're all equal anyway. You care what code runs and what data structures it manipulates, not what thread happens to be running.

Comment: "Those tasks are different enough that I don't know if a thread pool would be helpful." You can have a thread pool and still execute different tasks.

Comment: In my opinion a thread pool is a premature optimization.  I would start without it and prove there is a need.  I suspect you will not notice the overhead of threads without a pool.